# Can I get the IPFS hash from file (without uploading it & with java)?

Tags: web3j, ipfs, java, hash-algorithm

As far as I'm concerned IPFS client [uses the resulting SHA-256 hash from files, and also compatible with others](https://multiformats.io/multihash/), to index them in the IPFS Protocol.
My problem is that I'm not sure how to consistently generate the final IPFS hash from my file (.json), and to trust that the file will generate the same hash after uploading to IPFS with Pinata.

***I can*** get the hash of the .json file ***after uploading it to IPFS*** (with Pinata), **BUT** I would like to ***get the hash without uploading*** to ensure that I only upload the json file when the user signs the transaction of the the Smart Contract with Web3/Metamask.

My process is as following:

- My NFTs consist of a tokenID (numeric index) and a baseURI (IPFS hash).

1. When a user wants to create a new NFT, the fronted **webapp calls to the backend's** web service, **to get the IPFS hash of the resulting new NFT**.
2. Then, **the user  provides the IPFS hash** (retrieved previously from the backend's web service connected to Pinata Cloud), via Web3Js(Metamask) transaction, to the Smart Contract (NFT Creation).
3. After NFT creation, the **java app is also checking the SC events (via subscribe)** that the associated baseURI param is the same as the registered one in the cloud database table.

How could I achieve this? I do not see the way with Pinata's API, but I'm not sure how to manage it [with an Ipfs Java Client (I have been researching on this)](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/java-ipfs-http-client).

Comment: The only way I found is through this JS lib https://github.com/alanshaw/ipfs-only-hash/blob/dbb72ccfff45ffca5fbea6a7b1704222f6aa4354/test.js#L21-L33 . Did you find out something new on that topic?